# How to use function to create new dataframe column using other column values?

Tags: python, function, dataframe

I have a list of DOIs and Journal titles in a csv, now in a dataframe. I'm trying to reconstruct the journal url for v1 of the articles using a function. What is the correct way to create a new column using a function that uses values from existing columns in the dataframe?

The dataframe looks like this:

```
PMID    Journal     DOI
1234    medRxiv     10.1101/2020.09.30.320762
2345    bioRxiv     10.1101/2020.05.26.117549
```

The function I created:

```
def createURL (doi, journal) :
    url = 'https://www.'+journal+'.org/content/'+ str(doi)+'v1'
    
    return url
```

My attempt to call the function:

```
#this returns a Key Error ('PMID')
for row in dfRxiv :
    dfRxiv['URL'][row] = createURL(dfRxiv['DOI'][row], dfRxiv['Journal'][row])
```

I'm new to Python and I'm sure there's a better way to do this - I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty much there. You don't need to iterate through the rows or define a function - it's easier than that!:

```
dfRxiv['URL'] = 'https://www.' + dfRxiv['Journal'].astype('str') + '.org/content/' + dfRxiv['DOI'].astype('str') + 'v1'
```

**edit**
If you do want to use a function:

```
def createURL(df):
    url = 'https://www.' + df['Journal'].astype('str') + '.org/content/' + df['DOI'].astype('str') + 'v1'
    return url

dfRxiv['URL'] = createURL(dfRxiv)
```